# multiple wire decorators not working in lwc

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning, javascript, lightning-web-components

I have an lwc component with 2 picklist fields from contact object.
Below is the html and Js code snippets of the same:

HTML:

```html
<lightning-combobox
   data-id="cntype" 
   class="slds-m-bottom_small" 
   name="Functional Role" 
   label="Primary Functional Role" 
   value={value} 
   placeholder="-Select-" 
   options={pickListvaluesByRecordType} 
   onchange={onValueSelection}
></lightning-combobox>

<lightning-combobox
    data-id="cntype"
    class="slds-m-bottom_small"
    name="Business Role"
    label="Business Role"
    value={value}
    placeholder="-Select-"
    options={businessrole}
    onchange={onValueSelection}
></lightning-combobox>
```

JS:

```js
import {
  getPicklistValuesByRecordType,
  getbusinessrole
} from "lightning/uiObjectInfoApi";
import ccRecordID from '@salesforce/label/c.ContactRecordId';
import CONTACT_OBJECT from "@salesforce/schema/Contact";
export default class MyComponent extends LightningElement {
    @track businessrole;
    @track pickListvaluesByRecordType;
    @track contactType;

    /*picklist value 1 */
    @wire(getPicklistValuesByRecordType, {
        recordTypeId: ccRecordID,
        objectApiName: CONTACT_OBJECT
    })
    wiredRecordtypeValues({ data, error }) {
        if (data) {
            this.pickListvaluesByRecordType = data.picklistFieldValues.Functional_Role__c.values;
        } else if (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }

    /* picklist value 2 */
    @wire(getbusinessrole, {
        recordTypeId: ccRecordID,
        objectApiName: CONTACT_OBJECT
    })
    wiredBusinessRoleValues({ data, error }) {
        if (data) {
            this.businessrole = data.picklistFieldValues.Business_Role__c.values;
        } else if (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }

    /* OnvalueSelection Function */
    onValueSelection(event) {
        this.contactType = event.target.value;
        this.businessrole = event.target.value;
    }
}
```

Now, this one is working fine only when there is one wire decorator. If I update the JS with the above 2 decorators, the page itself is not rendering. There is no error but the page is not getting displayed.

Can anyone please let me know on how to get lwc working with 2 wire decorators included.

Thanks!

Comment: can you share your full js code ?

Comment: @Badbaxx, Rest all has normal import statement and handlesave methods. These are responsible for picklist fields in the page and when I include second wire method, page is not working. If i remove that, page is working fine.

Comment: I ask that because It could be interesting to see how you deal with *onValueSelection* fuction.

Comment: @Badbaxx, I have updated above js with onvalueSelection function.

Comment: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/use_flow_custom_property_editor_action_example

Comment: @Badbaxx, could you mention what this link is all about?

Comment: Hi, could you give the full JS file ? Or at least what is above class declaration (the imports). In case `getbusinessrole` is an Apex method, please provide the Apex code.
Be aware that javascript is case sensitive opposite to Apex which is not, this might be confusing.
Lastly, it seems that you copy paste your code. In this state it can't work as selecting a value on one picklist set the `contactType` and `businessrole` with the same value.

Comment: @SFDCUser This is an exemple of how to deal with multiple onChange event. I'm not really sure you can use twice the same onChange *onValueSelection* Value. Try with separate values : onValueSelection1 and onValueSelection2 for exemple

Comment: @Badbaxx, using twice the same event handler is perfectly fine. In this case I wouldn't recommend it as each picklist has its option list and selected value variable so would need two event handler to be correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@wire(getbusinessrole, {
```

Should probably be:

```
@wire(getPicklistValuesByRecordType, {
```

I can't see any other reason you'd get a failure.

P.S. When you include code on this site, make sure you show your import statements, too. This helps us confirm the data type(s) for the imported symbols.

Comment: sfdcfox, can we use same @wire methods for different picklist fields as one is holding Functional_Role__c field and another is holding Business_Role__c field?

Comment: @SFDCUser Certainly, although I don't see why you have two wire methods in this case, because all the data is available in one call.